# Repeating an annual cycle with Pandas in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, cycle

I am trying to manipulate annual cycles of data in pandas. I have created an annual cycle (including leap days) of rainfall data, where the index is a string representing the month and day.

I would like to repeat this data over a time period (say 1980-2020) with a datetime index. Is there a neat way to do this in pandas? The only way I can think of is to create an empty dataframe and cycle through the years, checking for leap years, but I am sure there must be a better way.

So far I've got:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import calendar

data = np.random.rand(366)
df_annual_cycle = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=['annual_cycle'],
    index=pd.date_range('2004-01-01','2004-12-31').strftime('%m-%d'),
    data=data
)

df_annual_cycle.head()

#        annual_cycle
# 01-01      0.863838
# 01-02      0.234168
# 01-03      0.368678
# 01-04      0.066332
# 01-05      0.493080


df_every_year=pd.DataFrame(
    columns=['rainfall'],index=pd.date_range('1980-01-01','2020-12-31')
)

for year in df_every_year.index.year:
    if calendar.isleap(year):
        df_every_year[
            df_every_year.index.year==year
        ] = df_annual_cycle.values
    elif ~calendar.isleap(year):
        df_every_year[
            df_every_year.index.year==year
        ] = df_annual_cycle.drop(index='02-29').values
```

I would prefer, ideally, not to have to convert to a numpy array using .values, as my dataframe has multiple (possibly changeable) columns.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else trying to do this, this is much faster (although still not very neat):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import calendar

data = np.random.rand(366)
df_annual_cycle = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=['annual_cycle'],
    index=pd.date_range('2004-01-01','2004-12-31').strftime('%m-%d'),
    data=data
)


years=np.arange(1980,2020)
df_every_year=pd.concat([df_annual_cycle]*40)
myindex=(np.repeat(years,366).astype(str)+df_every_year.index)
df_every_year.index=myindex
for year in np.arange(1980,2020):
    if ~calendar.isleap(year):
        df_every_year.drop(index=str(year)+'02-29',inplace=True)
df_every_year.index=pd.to_datetime(df_every_year.index,format='%Y%m-%d')
```